# How to calculate the mean and variance of this Ito integral?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, variance, itos-lemma, expected-value

I tried to calculate this integral use Ito's lemma, $W_{t}$ is the Wiener Process.
$$I_{T}=\int_{0}^{T}\sqrt{|W_{t}|}dW_{t}$$

We have 
$d f\left(W_{t}\right)=f^{\prime}\left(W_{t}\right) d W_{t}+\frac{1}{2} f^{\prime \prime}\left(W_{t}\right) d t$, by letting $f(W_{t})=\frac{2}{3}|W_{t}|^{\frac{3}{2}}$, we have $$d(\frac{2}{3}|W_{t}|^{\frac{3}{2}})=\sqrt{|W_{t}|}dW_{t}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|W_{t}|}}dt$$ Then we can write $$I_{T}=\frac{2}{3}|W_{T}|^{\frac{3}{2}}-\int_{0}^{T}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|W_{t}|}}dt$$ I don't know whether this is correct and I'm new to stochastic integral.  If above is correct, how to calculate $\mathbb{E}[I_{T}]$ and $Var(I_{T})$.

Comment: You’re trying to differentiate the function $f(x)=|x|$ which is tricky and not very rigorous in this context. You do not need Ito’s Lemma in this case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral $I_T$ is an Itô stochastic integral therefore its expectation is $0$. This is because $I_T$ is a martingale (see e.g. Theorem 4.3.1 in Shreve), hence:
$$\mathbb{E}[I_T]=I_0=0$$
You can also see this by considering the definition of a stochastic integral, which involves the sum of terms of the form $f(W_{t_i})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})$, and using the independence of Brownian increments $W_{t_i}-W_0$ and $W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}$.

From the above, we get:
$$\mathbb{V}[I_T]=\mathbb{E}[I_T^2]$$
Given $I_T$ is an Itô integral and that the process $Z_t\triangleq \sqrt{|W_t|}$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $W_t$, by [Itô's Isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry):
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[I_T^2]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^TZ_t^2\text{d}t\right]
\\[3pt]
&=\int_0^T\mathbb{E}[|W_t|]\text{d}t
\end{align}$$
$W_t$ is normally distributed. By symmetry of the Normal distribution, the expectation of $|W_t|$ is equal to twice the expectation of $1_{\{W_t\geq0\}}W_t$, namely:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[1_{\{W_t\geq0\}}W_t]&=\int_0^\infty w\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{w^2}{2t}}\text{d}w
\\[3pt]
&=\int_0^\infty v\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{v^2}{2}}\sqrt{t}\text{d}v
\\[3pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty ve^{-\frac{v^2}{2}}\text{d}v
\\[8pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}}
\end{align}$$
where we've made the change of variables $v=w/\sqrt{t}$. Thus $\mathbb{E}[|W_t|]=\sqrt{2t/\pi}$, from which it comes:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}[I_T]&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^T\sqrt{t}\text{d}t
\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{8}{9\pi}}T^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

**References**

Shreve, S. (2004). *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II*, Springer.